# Шляпы ломают форматирование

Tags: дефект, дизайн, новогодние-шляпы

Из-за шляп [текст не укладывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/412963/revisions) в отведённые для него рамки:

> [image: выход за границы]

Для ненавистников шляп - всё выглядит нормально:

> [image: в границах]